# Change color individual tab

Tags: ionic-framework

How to change the background color of the individual tab in ionic?

I tried to put a class or id in the tab, but it did not work.

I'm using ionic 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.tab-item {
  background-color: $energized;
  opacity: 1;
}
.tab-item+ .tab-item  {
  background-color: $balanced;
}
.tab-item+ .tab-item+ .tab-item  {
  background-color: $calm;
}

.tab-item+ .tab-item+ .tab-item+ .tab-item  {
  background-color: $positive;
}
```